# How do I fix the client error in package.json?

Tags: json, reactjs, windows, react-native

I have a project and I am trying to figure it out why it's not working. I clone it to my PC. Whenever i run npm start. This is what it give me. I don't know where and how to fix the error. Help will be much appreciate.

Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBvfe.jpg)

Comment: have you tried running npm install first?

Comment: yes I did run npm install